# I am trying to select three states in the same store but I am facing with problems

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am having issues with the store because in one store I have done 3 states I am using ngrx store in Angular.
The problem it is that the everything it is working but I have errors i the TS
I have edited question from the answer of the @Fartab code it is working but still showing some errors.

Here is the code what I have done so far.

```
  cluster = Map<string, ClusterItem>();

    this.store.select('technicalMatrix').subscribe(state => {
      this.cluster = state.technicalCluster;
      this.manufactures = state.manufacturer;
       this.store.select('technicalMatrix').subscribe(state => {
  this.cluster = ([...state.technicalCluster,
                          ...state.costCenter,
                          ...state.manufacturer]);
});
}

//  this is for the state [ts] Type 'Map<string, ClusterItem>' is not an array type
// for this.cluster it is showing this error
// Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword
```

Property 'set' is missing in type 'any[]'.
Here are my stores.

```
export interface ApplicationState {
  technicalMatrix: TechnicalMatrixState;
}
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ApplicationState> = {

  technicalMatrix: technicalMatrixReducer
};
export interface TechnicalMatrixState {
  costCenter: Map<string, ClusterItem>;
  technicalCluster: Map<string, ClusterItem>;
  manufacturer: Map<string, ClusterItem>;
  activeMatrixType: string;
  expandedTechnicalIds: Set<string>;
  filter: Filter;
}

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  costCenter: Map<string, ClusterItem>(),
  technicalCluster: Map<string, ClusterItem>(),
  manufacturer: Map<string, ClusterItem>(),
  activeMatrixType: '',
  expandedTechnicalIds: Set<string>(),
  filter: {name: ''}
};
import { ApplicationState } from '~/shared/store/reducers';
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

export const selectClusterItemDatabaseState = (state: ApplicationState) => state.technicalMatrix;
export const selectActiveMatrix = createSelector(selectClusterItemDatabaseState, state => state[state.activeMatrixType]);
export const selectActiveMatrixType = createSelector(selectClusterItemDatabaseState, state => state.activeMatrixType);
export const selectCostCenters = createSelector(selectClusterItemDatabaseState, state => state.costCenter);
export const selectTechnicalClusters = createSelector(selectClusterItemDatabaseState, state => state.technicalCluster);
export const selectManufacturers = createSelector(selectClusterItemDatabaseState, state => state.manufacturer);
```

And I have make a method here to see which is visible of the store.

```
setVisible() {
 this.selectedMatrix.forEach(clusterId => {
      const matrix = this.cluster.get(clusterId); //here is just one store selected this.cluster referes to the store state.technicalCluster
}
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what is your problem. Question is not clear.

Comment: @Fartab How to select 3 states in one store with the same variable declared ?

Comment: please mention your store state model

Comment: i mean ApplicationState

Comment: @Fartab I have write my ApplicationState

Comment: why you didn't put all of your app state in ApplicationState? something like this: interface ApplicationState {
  technicalMatrix;
  manufacturer;
  costCenter;
}

Comment: Because I have there only the technicalMatrix .
I will change now the code to show you where are the manufactures and others. see the edited code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
allClusters: Map<string, ClusterItem>;

this.store.select('technicalMatrix').subscribe(state => {
    this.allClusters = new Map([...state.technicalCluster, 
                                ...state.manufacturer, 
                                ...state.costCenter]);
});


setVisible() {
     this.selectedMatrix.forEach(clusterId => {
         const matrix = this.allClusters.get(clusterId);
     }
}
```

Comment: The code it is working bute it is saying me some errors 

[ts] Type 'Map<string, ClusterItem>' is not an array type